# Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined: this.ngControl.control is undefined in Ivy

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-ivy

Just as [this issue states](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35330), if you try to access an ngControl.control with a Directive:

```
export class DisabledDirective {
  @Input()
  set opDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
}
```

You will reach an error upon first rendering:

```
core.js:5828 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'disable' of undefined
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution in the given link is quite hacky and unreliable.

Until they fix the issue, simply guard the expression with if-s for the first rendering:

```
export class DisabledDirective {
  @Input()
  set opDisabled(condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    if(this.ngControl?.control){
       this.ngControl.control[action]();
    }
  }

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
}
```

ps.: notice the new safe/elvis operator which you can use in Angular 9 in the TS code too :)

Comment: Has this issue already been raised in the angular's github project?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is use the OnChanges lifecycle (as it's mentioned in the official issue)

```
@Directive({ selector: '([formControlName], [formControl])[disableControl]' })
export class DisableControlDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() disableControl = false;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.disableControl) {
      this.ngControl.control?.disable();
    } else {
      this.ngControl.control?.enable();
    }
  }

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}
}
```

The usage will be like

```
<input formControlName="id" [disableControl]="true" />
```